# Calculated field in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: report, cognos-bi, cognos-10

I am creating reports on Cognos Studio and trying to add a calculated field named Record. Following are the conditions used to create this calculated field:

Dataitem: Record:

`IF (com = ‘MASTERLINE’ THEN (com + ‘ ‘ + ML) ELSE (com + ‘ ‘ + ML1)`

Dataitem: com

`IF Acct_Prod = ‘MLAC’ THEN ‘MASTERLINE’ ELSE (IF Proc_type = ‘00’ THEN ‘LOAN’  ELSE ‘LINE’)`

Dataitem: ML

`IF Line_Num = ‘00’ THEN ‘’ ELSE Line_Num`

Dataitem: ML1

`IF Line_num =’00’ THEN ‘’ ELSE ‘Tied to ML’`

I am looknig for a combined if statement instead of creating extra data items. Can anyone guide?

Comment: What prevents you from simply replacing all terms by their definitions? Do you get a run time error?

Comment: It just makes it a complex query. Anyways, thanks for your response...

Comment: It may be complex to read afterwards but it won't be computationally complex, at least not more complex than it's components.

Comment: ok. Thank you for your valuable input